# iPhone mapkit driving directions

Tags: iphone, mapkit, driving-directions

I need to build an application similar to iPhone built-in maps. I want to give the start and end location and the route directions to reach there along with the distance. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following API to get the directions.You have to give start and endpoint latitude , longitude and it will display the result in an XML format.Then you can draw the route on map.

[LINK](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=41.029598,28.972985&destination=41.033586,28.984546&sensor=false)

Comment: Thanks For the help.Do you know the api to fetch location details using zipcode